# Would monopoles exist in numbers that cancel out?

Tags: magnetic-monopoles

Suppose magnetic monopoles exist.

Is there a reason to think that as much north monopole must exist as south, or even that if one exists then so must the other (could there be south without north or north without south)?

Comment: Another question: Do equal numbers of + and - electric charges exist?